# Can glsl shaders be compiled to Webassemly/wasm with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, glsl, webgl, webassembly

I am new to Unity and therefore I have a question, which might be obvious. When exporting a project which uses webgl as WASM are the shaders also compiled in web assembly or just the project code? How could I check this? I have read this https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/08/15/webassembly-is-here/ but it doesn’t mention specifically if the glsl shaders can be compiled as well. I appreciate any help/ guidance you can give me!

Comment: GLSL shaders run on the graphics card, not on the CPU/in the browser. They can't be compiled to webassembly.

Comment: @tkausl Thank you so much for this answer! Just to clarify how does it work with the shaders exactly if they can’t be compiled? Can anyone access them and see the code or where are they “saved” once a project is on the web ?

Comment: Anyone can access shaders on nearly any platform using any language. Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, C,C++, Java, Swift, ObjectiveC, JavaScript, WebAssembly, OpenGL, DirectX, Metal, Vulkan, it doesn't matter if they are compiled or not. All someone was to do is put in some OS level debugging hooks with standard available tools to look at your shaders. [Here's a whole blog where someone has looked through the shaders of popular games using those techniques](http://www.adriancourreges.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shaders are not compiled into WebAssembly. Shaders are written in Cg / HLSL and when you export Unity translates the shaders into GLSL and embeds the GLSL in the game. At runtime the game then uploads those GLSL shaders to WebGL.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just for my information: how does that work exactly ? Where is the GLSL Code stored so that it can be uploaded ? Could anyone who visits the website have access to it ?

Comment: Anyone who downloads any native game has access to your shaders. This has absolutely nothing to do with Unity or WebGL or WebAssembly. It's the way computers work. If your computer can read it then someone can use software to read it too.

Comment: @Angarakilkiri "Could anyone who visits the website have access to it ?" Of course, he _must_ have access to it to be able to use it.

Comment: It may still be possible to compile GLSL shaders to WebAssembly, since they can be compiled to LLVM IR using the [SPIRV-LLVM-Translator](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-LLVM-Translator).

Comment: @AndersonGreen, there's no point in compiling a shader into WebAssembly unless you **don't** want to run them on the GPU but instead want to emulate them in software, which is slow, and irrelevant to the question (which is about Unity)